# How to make different tabbed bootstrap forms talk to different controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to learn angular js and I have this problem.

I have a bootstrap tab as described by the bootstrap website (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). Each tab is a form, say login, sign up and forgot password and each form has an ng-app and an ng-controller of course with their respective ng-models.

The first tab (login) works just with the controller and does what I want.

My problem is that the second and third tabs do not go to their own controllers.

Also, on the first tab, the md-button attributes renders but on the second and third tab it doesn't (yes I have included ngMaterial in all the angular apps of the 3 controllers).

When I move the form of the signup to the first position (where login is currently is) it works.

I will be open to provide more details.

Please help me.

The html code is found below.

```
<div class="">



        <div style="margin-top:50px;" class="container mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">


<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="" data-target="#student" aria-controls="student" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Student</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="" data-target="#teacher" aria-controls="teacher" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Teacher</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="" data-target="#administrator" aria-controls="administrator" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Administrator</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="student">
        <div id="loginbox" ng-app="studentLogin">
<div class="panel panel-info" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">Student sign in</div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" ng-controller="StudentLoginController">

        <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12" ng-if="login_error_message" ng-cloak>
            <strong><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Error:</strong> {{login_error_message}} <span id="login-alert-message"></span>
        </div>

        <form id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="studentAuthForm" method="get">

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student ID number" required autofocus ng-model="studentNumber"/>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required autofocus ng-model="password"/>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                <!-- md-button -->

                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="authenticate();"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Login </md-button>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                        Add disclaimer here!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="teacher">
        <div id="loginbox">
     <div class="panel panel-info" >
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">Teacher sign in</div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
     </div>

          <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

           <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

            <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></i></span>
                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
            </div>


            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                <!-- Button -->

                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                        Add disclaimer here!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>



    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="administrator">
        <div id="loginbox" ng-app="administratorLogin">
<div class="panel panel-info" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">Administrator sign in</div>
        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" ng-controller="AdministratorLoginController">

        <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12" ng-if="login_error_message" ng-cloak>
            <strong><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Error:</strong> {{login_error_message}} <span id="login-alert-message"></span>
        </div>

        <form id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get">

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus ng-model="emailAddress">
            </div>

            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required autofocus ng-model="password">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox"         name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                <!-- Button -->

                <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"     ng-click="authenticateAdministrator();" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Login </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 control">
                    <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                        Add disclaimer here!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

The controller for the first tab is found below.

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('studentLogin' , ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('StudentLoginController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.authenticate = function () {

            if ($scope.studentNumber == undefined || $scope.password == undefined) {
                alert("Check") ;

            } else {
                var url = get_base_url() + 'student/authentication/login?studentNumber=' + $scope.studentNumber + '&password=' + $scope.password ;

                $http.post(url).then(
                    function (response) {

                        if (response.data.error == "true" ) {
                            $scope.login_error_message = response.data.result[0].message ;

                        } else {
                            alert ("Error") ;
                        }
                    }, function (response) {

                    }
                ) ;
            }
        }
    }) ;

})() ;
```

The controller for the third tab is found as below.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('administratorLogin' , ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('AdministratorLoginController', function ($scope, $http) {

        alert ("test") ;

        $scope.authenticateAdministrator = function () {

            alert ("test 2") ;

            var url = get_base_url() + 'administrator/authentication/login?emailAddress=' + $scope.emailAddress + '&password=' + $scope.password ;

            $http.post(url).then(
                function (response) {

                    if (response.data.error == "true" ) {
                        $scope.login_error_message = response.data.result[0].message ;
                    } else {
                        alert ("Error") ;
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    alert ("Service error.");
                }
            ) ;
        }
    }) ;
  })() ;
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen please see the changes above. If you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple ngApp directives in a single HTML document. You can read about this here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

In your case you can either register all controllers in a single module and use it as a bootstrapper in ngApp directive which is defined in a root html element. Or you can register your controllers in a separate modules, but set them as dependencies of the main module.

`angular.module('myModule', [DependencyModule1, DependencyModule2]);`

You can look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to use the same ng-app for all the tabs and then created seperate ng-clicks for each form in the same controller. It equally resolved the problem of the md-button.